# preg_match_all(): raw ASCII hex matching

Tags: php, regex, ascii, preg-match-all, hex

I'm trying to find a pattern for raw form of hexadecimal representation of ASCII characters. An example input looks like this (with apostrophes included):

```
'\x61\x62\x63\x87\x72\x52'
```

or

```
'\x61\x62\x63\x64\x61\x42\x93\x3a'
```

The thing is, `\x61\x62\x63` is always the same. I tried many different patterns, for ex.:

```
'/\'\\x61\\x62\\x63(.+)\'/i'
```

and

```
'/\'\x61\x62\x63(.+)\'/i'
```

and various replacements for `(.+)` but I can't make it working right.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

PS. Note that *input* contain a **hexadecimal representation** of ASCII characters.

Comment: How is it not working right? What do you get? What did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include a single `\` in a PHP string you need to use `\\`, and to include a single `\` in a regex you need to use `\\`.  Combine these requirements and a single backslash in a PHP regex will look like `\\\\`.  Try the following:

```
$pattern = "/'\\\\x61\\\\x62\\\\x63(.+)'/i";
```

For example:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, "'\\x61\\x62\\x63\\x64\\x61\\x42\\x93\\x3a'", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => '\x61\x62\x63\x64\x61\x42\x93\x3a'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => \x64\x61\x42\x93\x3a
        )

)
```

ideone: http://ideone.com/RIDa64